# Apparmor on Docker Swarm

Tags: security, docker, apparmor, swarm

I read on the Docker documentation that it is possible to load custom AppArmor policies and ask Docker to load them for a specific container.

Is it possible to use these policies also on Docker Swarm services (provided that all nodes of the cluster have the AppArmor policies)?

Thanks!

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)